# How to render sub-template includes in ejs.renderFile?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have an EJS template that has `<%- include('other-template'); %>` in it.

When I render the template with Express.js, it works well.

However, when I do it with `await ejs.renderFile('main.ejs', {async: true})`, instead of seeing the rendered sub-template, all I get is `[object Promise]` string.

What should I do to make EJS render the sub-template correctly?

Comment: Very interesting.  To be clear, if you do `result = ejs.renderFile('main.ejs', { async: true}))` you get a Promise that, when awaited, returns a string that contains something like `[object Promise]\r\nAnd The rest of your main.ejs template here...`.  I wonder if it's a bug?

Comment: @Wyck: exactly. I'm also inclined to think that it's a bug: when I use a callback variant of `renderFile` instead of async/await one, the sub-template is rendered correctly. I'll check twice tomorrow, and shall post an answer to my own question if it appears that this is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `async:true`, `include` also returns a promise, so try awaiting each partial: add `await` on each `include`:

```
<%- await include('other-template'); %>
```